# Blueprism : Get Text in region mode is not working

Tags: ocr, blueprism

When I tried to read text with OCR is throwing following error.

> Error: Failed to perform step 1 in Read Stage 'Read Operate Text' on page 'Attach and Open Solution' - The file exists.

But this was working for past days and this issue happening in particular VM, but same stage is working in another VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I get this error occur when the temp folder has become full on the machine. Therefore, one thing you could try is clearing down the TEMP folder on the machine; this is usually C:\Temp\ but you can check the Windows variable %TEMP% to be sure.

Issue fixed after doing this.